# Slack SCIM API Filtering on Active

Tags: slack-api, scim

When attempting to hit the Slack SCIM API I am unable to filter users on the active field. Am I forming this query incorrectly?

I'm currently using `GET` `https://api.slack.com/scim/v1/Users/?filter=active eq "true"`

When filtering on email for example, the results are as expected. The same goes for other fields. Only active fails.

It produces this error message:

```
{
    "Errors": {
        "description": "invalid_query (is_aggregate_call=1)",
        "code": 400
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jonah, how to write GET rest query in c# or code for SCIM api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The Slack SCIM API filter functionality](https://api.slack.com/scim#filter) only supports `filter`ing on `username`, `email`, `restricted`, `ultra_restricted` so unfortunately what you're looking to do is not possible at the moment.

Excerpt from docs:

> Filters may be applied to the username and email user attributes, with
>   the addition of two membership filters:

---

Definitely consider writing in to [submit your use case/suggestion/feedback](https://slack.com/help/requests/new)!

Comment: @AmayKulkarni please use https://slack.com/help/requests/new but I also have updated the link in my original post which had an error in it